# javascript: adding objects to an array changes the object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create an array of color values. I define the color values as objects:

```js
    let rgbPalette = [];
    var color1 = {r: 152, g: 52, b: 211, a: 255};
    rgbPalette.push(color1);
    var color2 = {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0};
    rgbPalette.push(color2);

    console.log(rgbPalette);
```

when log the array to the console, i get different property values of the objects:

```
rgbPalette:  
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {r: 151, g: 51, b: 210, a: 255}
1: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 8}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Your code does not appear to do what you say it does. Perhaps you left out some important details.

Comment: Or all of them.

Comment: Something must be mutating the object before you examine it in the console. (feel free to post a MCVE so there's something to debug and it could be reopened)

Comment: ah OK, so I'm calling this function with an 'await' from another asynchronous function. This is being developed in Electron, so it is using a chromium browser. I think the other issue mentioned by @CertainPerformance is similar to what's happening here. But I need to return this array to the async function, so tricking the console won't be enough. Any ideas?

Comment: update: i see, just adding a print line with JSON.stringify in the parent function reveals that the value is being passed correctly. thanks for your help.